# JSON serialize a custom C# struct to a string, not an Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, struct

I've looked at various questions but I am unsure of how to implement this.

I have a custom struct, which currently has no public properties on it. When it is returned via WebApi (not doing any fancy serialization, just returning the custom struct itself), it is returned as an object `{}`.

```
public struct CustomStruct
{
    private string myProperty;

    ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return this.myProperty;
    }

    ...

}
```

The custom struct itself is the type of a property on a parent class, which serializes to:

```
{ "MyProp1":"value1","MyProp2":"value2","MyCustomStruct":{} }
```

When I override ToString() on the custom struct I want to output one of the private properties. Can I achieve a similar behaviour when returning the object to JavaScript-land, as a JSON object?

E.g. my private property is a string, called "myProperty", set to "test".
If I added a public property called "MyProperty", I'd get the following output:

```
{ "MyProp1":"value1","MyProp2":"value2","MyCustomStruct":{ "MyProperty":"test" } }
```

When what I really want is:

```
{ "MyProp1":"value1","MyProp2":"value2","MyCustomStruct":"test" }
```

Hope this makes sense.

Here are the related questions that haven't really helped me much. Would like to avoid using JSON.NET if possible but will go for that if it is the only way:

[JSON.Net Struct Serialization Discrepancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804230/json-net-struct-serialization-discrepancy)

[C# custom json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625631/c-sharp-custom-json-serialization)

[JSON.NET with Custom Serializer to a custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607099/json-net-with-custom-serializer-to-a-custom-object)

[JSON serialization of enum as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441290/json-serialization-of-c-sharp-enum-as-string)

[JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize - how to change field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100191/javascriptserializer-deserialize-how-to-change-field-names)

Comment: What are you currently using for serialization? i.e. what version of WebAPI? If it's the latest version you're already using JSON.Net if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: MVC 4, .NET 4.0... yes there is a reference to JSON.NET created by default, I could use it, at the moment I am simply returning a collection of my classes, not an ActionResult/ContentResult or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done for now, is add a second property on the parent CustomClass class...

```
public string MyCustomStructValue { get { return MyCustomStruct.ToString(); } }
```

then add the `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute to the original property...

```
[IgnoreDataMember]
public CustomStruct MyCustomStruct { get; set; }
```

which works fine with the following action:

```
public IEnumerable<CustomClass> Get()
{
    return GetResults();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same challenge. I solved it by writing a custom JsonConverter that uses the objects ToString method when converting:

```
public class ToStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then using it like this as JsonConverter attribute:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ToStringConverter))]
public AnotherObjectWithToString MyObject { get; set; }
```

I should note that this can only be used for serialization as deserialization would require the ToString result to converted back into a object and that will vary by type.